/bin/sh: 0: pipeline@tmp/durable-abcdef/script.sh.copy: No such file or directory
I am adding Jenkins in Android project
and the build my one of my branches in MultiProject pipeline job.
but it is giving “/bin/sh: 0: pipeline@tmp/durable-abcdef/script.sh.copy: No such file or directory”
that is my pipline code:
  pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        JAVA_OPTS = "-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400"
    }


    options {
            // prevent multiple builds from running concurrently, that come from the same git branch
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }


    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                sh '''
                echo "This is a temporary script" > /workspace/script.sh.copy
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
                // Add steps to test if needed
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                // Add deployment steps if needed
            }
        }
    }
}


your agent is 'any', so is you have some nodes, may it run on another machine?

I have the same issue, it happens some times and some times not. In my case I have a multiplatform parallel block: sometimes fails on windows, sometimes fails on mac

Maybe the problem is that you don't have /workspace dir, so you have add correct output directory
sh """
            echo "This is a temporary script" > ${WORKSPACE}/script.sh.copy
   """

or
sh """
            echo "This is a temporary script" > script.sh.copy
   """


it's Mac system and workspace dir also been created with 3 files jenkins-log.txt,jenkins-result.txt.tmp and script.sh.
